# How to find the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ using the associated map of spectra?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I want to know how do you use the map $$^a\varphi : \mathrm{Spec} \,\mathbb{Z}[i]\to \mathrm{Spec}\, \mathbb{Z}$$

that is given by $p \mapsto \varphi^{-1}({p})$, where $\varphi : \mathbb{Z} \to\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is the inclusion map, to find the 'points' in $\mathrm{Spec}\, \mathbb{Z}[i]$?

This question is an example in Shafarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry (pg. 6). There the author writes that "$(^a\varphi)^{-1}(\{(p)\})$ is the set of prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ that divide $p$". I want to know how can I verify this?

I must be doing something very wrong because I've found that the set ought to contain the ideals that are divisible by $p$.

Also, how is this map any useful in finding the points in the spectrum of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$? How would you go about using this map to find, say, what $(^a\varphi)^{-1}(\{(17)\})$ is? This example also isn't clear as to how can this map guarantee that the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are only those that are in the sets $(^a\varphi)^{-1}(\{(p)\})$ for every prime number $p$.

Comment: The idea is that the points in the preimage of $p$ should correspond (in the obvious way) to the prime ideals of in $\mathbb Z[i]/p = \mathbb F_p[x]/(x^2+1)$.

Comment: @Asvin Do you know where can I go to read about this that doesn't explain things in very technical jargon, along with hopefully answering my other questions?

Comment: Depends on what you want to learn. If you want to learn number theory, then most standard number theory textbooks go through the stuff without mentioning any explicit algebraic geometry. Even if you want to learn geometry, it might be a good idea to learn algebraic number theory. If you want to learn algebraic geometry, then I am not sure what a non technical introduction would be, sorry. I am sure there are lots of posts discussing this on stackexchange though.

Comment: @Asvin I'm not looking to go very deeply into the subject at this moment, and only looking for help with this particular problem which I found interesting. I wasn't able to find the relevant post that answers my specific questions or I wouldn't have asked here.

Comment: I just meant you could find posts talking about introductions to algebraic geometry, not about the specific question. For this specific question, it really isn't that hard. Let me try and write a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any general ring map $f: B\to A$, let $f'$ denote the induced map on the Spec. Let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal of $B$ and let us investigate what the prime ideals of $A$ that map to $\mathfrak p$ are.

That is, we want $\mathfrak q \subset A$ such that $f^{-1}(\mathfrak q) = \mathfrak p$. In particular, $f(\mathfrak p) \subset \mathfrak q$. Therefore, the primes $\mathfrak q$ that we want are certainly contained in the Spec of $A/f(\mathfrak q)A$.

Next, we have an induced map $\overline f: B/\mathfrak p \to A/f(\mathfrak p)A$. Now, any element $\overline b \in B/\mathfrak p$ will certainly not map to any of the primes $\mathfrak q$ that we are looking for. That is to say, the primes we are looking for are contained in $(B/\mathfrak p)^{-1}(A/f(\mathfrak p)A) = A \otimes_B\kappa(B)$ where $\kappa(\mathfrak p)$ is the residue field at $\mathfrak p$.

In fact, a little more thought will show that the primes of $A \otimes_B\kappa(B)$ are exactly what we are looking for.

If you don't understand this answer, the first thing to do would be to make sure that you understand the correspondence between primes of $B$ containing $\mathfrak p$ and primes of $B/\mathfrak p$ and similarly, for any multiplicative set $S$, the primes of $S^{1}B$ and primes of $B$ avoiding $S$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I need to start with some elementary level texts and brush up on this material.